# subgroups of order $p^2$

Tags: abstract-algebra

How many subgroups of order $p^2$ does the abelian group $\mathbb{Z}_{p^3} \oplus \mathbb{Z}_{p^2}$ have? Hint: Every cyclic group of order n contains a unique subgroup of order m for all divisors m of n.

Proof:there are two types of groups of order $p^2$: cyclic, and non-cyclic.

non-cyclic: such a subgroup must be of the form HxK, where H is a subgroup of order $p$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{p^3}$, and K is a subgroup of order $p$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{p^2}$.

since there is only ONE such subgroup in each factor, we conclude the sole non-cyclic group of order $p^2$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{p^3} \oplus \mathbb{Z}_{p^2}$ is: $<p^2> x <p>.$

cyclic: subgroup K of order $p^2$ of $\mathbb{Z}_{p^3} \oplus \mathbb{Z}_{p^2}$,

where K = <(a,b)>, contains either $a$ as order $p^2$ (and b is arbitrary), or $b$ is of order $p^2$ and $a$ is of order $1$ or $p$.

there are $p^3-p^2$ elements of order $p^2$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{p^3}$, and $p^2-p$ elements of order $p^2$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{p^2}$.

this means we have a total of $p^4-p^3 + p^3-p^2 = p^4-p^2$ elements of order $p^2$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{p^3} \oplus \mathbb{Z}_{p^2}$.

since each distinct subgroup accounts for $p^2-p$ of these elements (a cyclic group of order $p^2$ has $p^2-p$ elements of order $p^2$), we must have:

$\frac{p^4 - p^2}{p^2 - p} = \frac{p^2(p^2 - 1)}{p(p-1)} = p^2+p$

cyclic subgroups of order $p^2$.

this gives us $p^2+p+1$ subgroups of order $p^2$ in all.

Is this right?

Comment: Well the statement that there are $p^3-p^2$ elements of order $p^2$ in ${\mathbb Z}_{p^3}$ is wrong. I don't know where you got that from! The number is $p^2-p$. However, strangely enough, the statement that there are $p^4-p^2$ elements of order $p^2$ in ${\mathbb Z}_{p^3}\oplus {\mathbb Z}_{p^2}$ is right, so your answer is right.